# Concatenate lists into single list

Tags: r

I have an array "wc" and it contains lists of numbers. I want to append these lists into single string and separate them with ";".

wc[1] = "235" "4" "6"

wc[2] = "34" "45" "41" "8"

wc[3] = "3" "45" "65"

so on till wc[9]

output should be 235 4 6; 34 45 41 8; 3 45 65

```
temp = ""
for (i in 1:length(wc))
{
temp = gsub(" ", " ",toString(c(wc[1:9])))

}
```

but output i am getting is

c("235","4","6"), c("34", "45", "41", "8"), ...

Comment: Mmh... looking at your code it seems like you need to learn and practice with R much more... First strings cannot be concatenated using '+', but you should use paste. Also `+=` does not exist in R and `str` it's normally used to see the structure of an object, not to turn an object to string... Please, try to study R language a bit more and you'll probably be able to solve these very simple issues by yourself

Comment: so your object wc is an R list containing vectors of characters?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that wc is an R list object containing vectors:

```
paste(sapply(wc,function(x){paste(x, collapse = " ")},simplify = T),collapse = ";")
```

Hope this is what you were looking for.